# How do I assign a related object in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Im my iPhone project, I have a data model with 2 objects: Profile and Contact. They are related to each other, with 1 Profile having many Contacts. Here is what I'm not sure about:

What is the right way to assign a Profile to a Contact when I add the Contact to the database?

I know how to add the contact to the database, but I need to know the right way to add the profile.

```
self.moc = [((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) managedObjectContext];
Contact *contact = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
contact.recordID = recID;
contact.profile = ????????
NSError *err = nil;
[self.moc save:&err];
```

Do I need to fetch the Profile first? Do I use a separate managedObjectContext, or the same one?

I have the first name of the profile, which I know I can use to fetch it like this:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName like %@)", appDelegate.currentProfile];
Profile *fetchedData = (Profile *)[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
```

I think I could do it like this, but if somebody could give me a code block with the best practice, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fetch the profile first, you can use the same MOC. Then just assign it to the profile property on the Contact.

`[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Profile" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc]` is not returning a Profile object though. It returns an entity description.

`+ (NSEntityDescription *)entityForName:(NSString *)entityName inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context`

You need to use a fetch request on the MOC. Checkout this:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/core-data-one-line-fetch.html

Comment: Thanks, thats good advice. I need to access this profile alot in my app. Would it make sense to fetch it once, and assign it to a property in my app delegate? Right now I am storing the first name of the profile like that to keep track, but it might be easier to just use the Profile object. Would the reference to it break if the profile was updated though?

Comment: If you have all your RFI setup correctly on your relationships, but it should be fine. I would always fetch it instead of holding a reference. if you change your design, having references to MOs for long periods can make your code fragile. Setup a DAO to handle all your managed object loads to encapsulate and facilitate code reuse.